# Calculate cluster accuracy of two clustering outcomes

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

So say I have two clustering outcomes that look like this:

```
clustering = [[8, 9, 10, 11], [14, 13, 4, 7, 6, 12, 5, 15], [1, 2, 0, 3]]
correct_clustering = [[2, 8, 10, 0, 15], [12, 13, 9, 14], [11, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7]]
```

How would I go about comparing the outcome contained in `clustering` to the one contained in `correct_clustering`. I want to have some number between 0 and 1. I was thinking about calculating the fraction of pairs which are correctly clustered together in the same cluster. But can't think of a programmatic way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Rand Index**:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import comb

def rand_index_score(clusters, classes):

    tp_plus_fp = comb(np.bincount(clusters), 2).sum()
    tp_plus_fn = comb(np.bincount(classes), 2).sum()
    A = np.c_[(clusters, classes)]
    tp = sum(comb(np.bincount(A[A[:, 0] == i, 1]), 2).sum()
             for i in set(clusters))
    fp = tp_plus_fp - tp
    fn = tp_plus_fn - tp
    tn = comb(len(A), 2) - tp - fp - fn
    return (tp + tn) / (tp + fp + fn + tn)

clusters = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

classes = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]

rand_index_score(clusters, classes)
0.6764705882352942
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best practice measures are indeed based on pair counting.

In particular the **adjusted Rand index** (ARI) is the standard measure here.

You don't actually count pairs, but the number of pairs from a set can trivially be *computed* using the binomial, simply `(n*(n-1))>>2`.

You'll need this for each cluster and each cluster intersection.

The results of all intersections are aggregated, and it is easy to see that this is invariant to the permutation of clusters (and hence to the cluster labels). The Rand index is the **accuracy of predicting whether two objects a, b are in the same cluster, or in different clusters**. The ARI improves this by adjusting for chance: in a very unbalanced problem, a random result can score a high accuracy, but in ARI it is close to 0 on average.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `adjusted_rand_score` in `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

clustering = sorted((i, num) for num, lst in enumerate(clustering) for i in lst)
clustering = [i for _, i in clustering]
# [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

correct_clustering = sorted((i, num) for num, lst in enumerate(correct_clustering) for i in lst)
correct_clustering = [i for _, i in correct_clustering]
# [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0]

ari = adjusted_rand_score(correct_clustering, clustering)
# -0.012738853503184737
```

The function returns values between 1 and -1 so to get a value between 0 and 1 you need to rescale:

```
ari_scaled = (ari + 1) / 2
# 0.49363057324840764
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: This is *not* the proper way to do this. Because there is no reason to assume that the clusters are ordered the same way. Check the *literature* on why the usual measure is the ARI.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You are right. Can you show how to implement ARI for multiple clusters in Python?